# Internet Explorer: Broken Underlines

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, underline, smallcaps

I'm having some trouble getting this layout to work correctly in IE. The problem is that when I have a bit of small-caps, underlined text, an image with vertical-align set to middle breaks up the underline. Lower case letters have their underline shifted down. [See the picture.](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7329/textw.png)

This looks fine in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but it's broken in every version of IE that I tried, including 8. This happens for underlined links as well. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img { vertical-align: middle; }
        span { text-decoration: underline; font-variant: small-caps; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="pic.png">
    <span>Abc QWerty AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are the image and its alignment actually relevant to this question?

Comment: @Rob: Not as far as I can tell. I get this also without the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about CSS validation adding a `zoom:1` declaration (or any other [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) invoking declaration) to your span style will solve the problem (in IE6/7 at least).

Comment: @Richard: Hmm, can't see any effect of this. The underlines still have different distances to each letter...

Comment: @Oliver: I've tested it again and the `zoom:1` solution works (for the test case in the question) for me in IE6. If you're having the problem on a more complex page you should ask a new question posting your code.

Comment: I'll have to retest. FWIW, in my case the text wasn't explicitly underlined like in the example but only implicitly because it was also a link (i.e. `<a href=...`)

Answer (score 0):

I also haven't managed to get this to work (`zoom:1` does nothing for me). I now resorted to using `border-bottom` instead of `underline`...